# Windows 2012 R2 Network Location Awareness madness - How to set type or name?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

I'm going a little crazy here. I have a newly built Windows 2012 R2 Datacenter edition VM running on VMWare ESX 5.1 with 2 NIC's and I'm unable to control any of the NLA (Network Location Awareness) settings. This machine is NOT joined to the domain (yet). This is important as the network location determines what firewall rules are applied.

In Windows 2008 R2 I used to be able to set the domain name suffix and the system would make the network type (Private/Public) clickable, and allow me to choose a different network type. It would also take the domain name suffix and name the network location as such. This is not happening in Windows 2012.

I've looked over a bunch of articles that either show how to use PowerShell to adjust this or how to use GPO or Local Security Policy. I've tried adjusting this via LSP and GPO, by allowing user to change all attributes, however after a reboot, none of the items (name, icon, etc) are adjustable, nor does NLA properly name the network based on the DNS suffix.

**1. Do the Local Security Policies (or GPO) actually change anything? If so, now that I’ve allowed changes by a user to all the network locations, how does a user change them?**

**2. Does Windows 2012 no longer respect the DNS suffix for a NIC? I would like to have the network name to be the same as the DNS suffix.**

I did some more testing and I created 2 domain controllers. I added a 2nd private NIC to the server with a completely different subnet. The network identifies this network connection as a Domain connection and names the connection as such (same name as the domain)!

**3. Is there a way to change this network location type and name?! This 2nd NIC should NOT be part of the domain!!! (It needs different firewall rules and different DNS suffix!).**

Is it me or did MS really drop the ball on this one in Windows 2012?

-Thanks
Paul

Comment: "This machine is NOT joined to the domain (yet)." Why not? It seems silly to set up your NLA when it will just change to domain when you add it.

Comment: Because I'm testing two scenarios, first that's not on the domain and second that is on the domain. The question does not change, so I'm not sure why you're inquiring about this.

Comment: To be clear you have 2 NICs on a DC but don't want one of the NICs to be a part of the domain that the domain controller participates in?

Comment: Jim B, I want the network location for the other NIC to be Private and not Domain. This is so the firewall policies can be properly assigned for this 2nd NIC. I want to be able to control FW policies based on the NL profiles, but this is beginning to look like a bad idea to rely on NL.

Comment: From a security perspective, it would be more proper to not multi home and use some kind of firewall to do this for you. This all depends on your environment though.

Comment: @JimB, It seems that on domain controllers all network cards will just go under the Domain profile.

Comment: @PawełCzopowik correct, afaik there is no way around that.(since anything from the DC would be domain traffic)

Answer (score 1):

You can change this on a granular level directly to each interface via PowerShell. Each interface in the machine receives it's own Index number which you specify the Network Type. The only caveat that you need to understand is that you can only change to either public or private. Domain only gets selected after joining the domain so since you are testing I would suggest you test everything first not on the domain and then join the domain and I suspect everything will be configured like you need it to be. You could also export your finished firewall rules to a settings file and human readable file and compare the human readable file using winmerge or something similar to verify or determine any changes after joining the domain. Let me know if you need help doing that and I can explain exporting the firewall as well if needed.

Check out this tutorial on how to do this via powershell: http://www.1337admin.org/windows-server/windows-server-2012-r2/change-network-location-using-powershell-in-windows/

Comment: If this does not work for you please run as admin from DOS the following command: "sc query state= all > c:\all_services.txt" without the quotes and post the output from the txt file and I can verify that all needed services are running.

Comment: Thanks Brad, I've been exporting FW rules for related purposes so I'll have to check this out next time I get a weekend to experiment. What I did realize is that MS changed the way this behaves in 2012 so a lot of the articles or GPO's no longer relate or work :(

Comment: You can also do this in the registry,  check out: http://www.1337admin.org/windows-server/windows-server-2012-r2/change-network-type-in-the-windows-registry/